# Finding minimum of max function, subject to constraint, in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Ok, so I have a function that takes the maximum of a 16 different functions. I want to find the minimum of this function subject to the condition that this function is equal to another function. This is what the code looks like, (`H1,...,H16` are all column vectors):

```
function f = opt(a,b,c)
F1 = a*mean(H1) + b*var(H1)+ c*skewness(H1);
...*more functions here*...
F15 = a*mean(H15) + b*var(H15)+ c*skewness(H15);
F16 = a*mean(H16) + b*var(H16)+ c*skewness(H16);
FVEC = [F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16];
[ max, max_index ] = max(FVEC);
f = max;
end
```

The constraint I want it basically that the above function should be equal to the first one in the list:

```
opt(a,b,c) = a*mean(H1) + b*var(H1)+ c*skewness(H1)
```

I think I'm supposed to use `fmincon`, but despite my repeated attempts, I seem to be running into issues, plus it does not look like it supports constraints depending on another function (although I might be misreading the docs). Is this the right function to use? What is the best way to approach this problem? I am very new to MATLAB and, so, I'm not familiar with what a typical approach would look like.

Comment: I don't understand the close vote? I get that it is a simple question, but if you need me to add more info or something, please let me know!
An anonymous close vote is not helping me understand why you think this is a poor question, or unsuitable for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max function is non-differentiable. Most solvers expect smooth functions (including `fmincon`). Luckily there is a simple linear formulation:

```
min y
y >= v(i) for all i
```

`y` will automatically assume the largest value of the `v(i)`.

Your constraint would be

```
y = v(1)
```

In this case we can even drop the `min y`.

This would enforce the first set of observations to be the maximum `v`. I am not sure, but this could lead to an infeasible model (if it cannot arrange a,b,c in such a way).